# How does a bootstrap program do dual booting of OS

Tags: operating-system, bootloader, bios

I understand that the bootstrap program runs initial diagnostics and then calls the bootloader from a fixed location.
When my had just two windows OS(example WINDOWS 7 and WINDOWS XP), a windows bootloader used to provide option of switching between the two operating systems. Once I installed Ubuntu (and grub becomes the bootloader), I am first asked to choose between windows and linux and then once I choose windows, I get the windows bootloader screen to choose between two windows. 
My understanding was that there can be only one bootloader at a fixed location which is known to the bootstrapper. So in this particular case how do the windows and linux bootloader coexist?

Comment: It is called a BIOS, not a bootstrap program...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootloaders can exist in multiple places.

There is one MBR (Master Boot Record) but there are multiple partitions. Each partition can have a bootloader in its Volume Boot Record (VBR) - the first sector of a bootable partition. You can have a bootloader on the MBR and/or within a VBR, so the MBR will chain to the secondary bootloader in the VBR. This is how you see Grub first, then Windows 7. Grub is on the MBR. But if you reinstall Windows, it will stomp on the MBR and put its bootloader back.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record

Comment: so when I install a new OS the bootloader of the existing OS residing  in the MBR is moved to a differnt partition and the bootloader for the new operating system is placed in the MBR?

Comment: No. The MBR is simply overwritten, or left alone, depending on where your new OS bootloader is installed. Linux is friendly and lets you choose. Windows is not so friendly and creates a special 100MB partition and installs its bootloader there, but also writes the MBR. That means the Windows 7 MBR is just a chain boot to the VBR in the special partition.

Answer (score 1):

mrjoltcola's answer is great and applicable to Legacy MBR-style bootloaders.  A few notes on UEFI booting:

- unlike the MBR system which is device-specific, UEFI uses boot paths:  a fully-qualified path to any file that is an OS bootloader
- there is no practical limitation in UEFI on the number of OS bootloaders you can configure on your system--just add the path to it; in contrast, a hard drive can only have one MBR and one VBR per partition

A lot more could be said about UEFI booting -- I'm just attempting to answer the original question as to how a UEFI system would handle it.